# Can DB::transaction() execute Eloquent queries as transaction?

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Me: THIS IS A HYBRID QUESTION |
Visitor: (wtf?) what this means?

I'm asking 2 questions in one (as it tightly coupled)

Using: Laravel 5.5 & Mysql

## 1. How do I delete related models in eloquent?

I'm trying to delete `User` which has the following relations

belongsTo `Address`,
belongsTo `Package`,
hasMany   `Orders`,
hasMany   `Comments`

`Orders` cascade when `User` or `Product` gets deleted
`COmments` cascade when `User` or `Post` gets deleted.

Now how do I can delete `User` & automatically have associated `orders` & `comments` deleted?

when I try to delete with `$user->delete()` laravel throws exception:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cybertron`.`comments`, CONSTRAINT `comments_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `users` where `id` = 4)
```

So I decided to use a transaction to delete, User, associated orders & comments,
To make sure everything gets deleted.

But I didn't find any transaction in eloquent but in query builder (DB).

## 2. if I use transaction from DB & use eloquent to delete user (`$user->delete`) will this consider as a transaction?

like:

```
DB::transaction(function() {

      $user->comments->delete();
      $user->orders->delete();
      $user->delete();
});
```

If not then how can I have a transaction with Eloquent ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have [Eloquent events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events) For deleting but you can also override default delete method like so:

   ```
   public function delete()
   {
       \DB::transaction(function() {
           $this->comments()->delete();
           $this->orders()->delete();
           parent::delete(); 
        });
   }
   ```
2. Yes, Eloquent doesn't have transaction itself. You use transactions as you showed and wrap Eloquent or query builder in it. Be aware that in your case you should use `comments()` and `orders()`  instead of `comments` and `orders`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I actually figured it out that night after spending an hour searching & testing. 
Your answer is absolutely what should be the solution for this case.

Comment: And in this case `comments()` should be used instead `comments` because we are not dealing with a collection but a model am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is because we are using relationship and if want to delete relationship items () should be added

Comment: best would be to return parent:delete() and return the results of the transaction to maintain laravel functionality. (determine if the record got deleted or not)

Answer (score 1):

@Marcin

if you are using events on model, in order to cascade delete, you need to make sure you understand differences between running delete on a Query object vs running delete on a Model object

For example :
$this->orders()->delete();
 - this line is not actually loading Order models
 - $this->orders() - returns a Query Object
 - this line will actually run a DELETE SQL statement

In order to launch deleting event on order when deleting a user, you would have to do a foreach
foreach($user->orders as $order) $order->delete();

when user::deleting event is launched, load all orders of the user and call delete;
this will fire order::deleting event where we are going to load all comment Objects and delete them also

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. This will help.